# Efficient way to check if elements of an array is a substring of elements in another array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two arrays:

1. `@array1` contains `blah1` through `blah100`.
2. `@array2` contains `Name: creating "blah1"` through `Name: creating "blah100"`.

I need to check that each element from `@array1` is in `@array2` but the `Name: creating` part is getting in the way.

What is the best route to make sure that all elements from `@array1` are in `@array2`?

Maybe the use of regexes for matching while looping through `@array1` against `@array2`?
Is there another faster way?

Do `array_diff`, `intersect`, or `unique` work when there is a noisy string in one of the arrays?

OR

maybe manipulate @array2 so that it gets rid of `Name: creating` part for each data?

Which way would be faster?

Comment: Do you have any control over creating of these arrays? Or you get them from somewhere.

Comment: What result do you want? Is a boolean meaning "matches" or "not matching" enough, or what else is wanted?

Comment: no control on the creation of those arrays. @user4035

Comment: @AdrainHHH Boolean of "all" (not just a few) of the array1 data is in array2

Comment: @ealeon Unfurtunately, there is no other way, then comparing them element by element, using a regexp. And checking, that their lengths are equal.

Comment: @user4035 ah I see. well which way would be faster? using regexp or just manipulate array2 so that it gets rid of Name: creating which then I can take advantage of array_diff?

Comment: Are the arrays sorted as you seem to indicate?

Comment: @ealeon I would recommend regexp - you won't need to loop through the array twice: 1 for creating the trimmed version, and second in array_diff for comparison.

Comment: @ealeon Does every element of array2 actually say Name: just like that? I am assuming that Name is a changing string that represents someone's name, not a literal string "Name." I thought that the first responder would update their answer to fix this issue, but there have been no changes, so I am providing my own answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
die if @array1 != @array2;
for (0..$#array1) {
   die if $array2[$_] ne qq{Name: creating "$array1[$_]"};
}
```

or if the *Name* part is variable,

```
die if @array1 != @array2;
for (0..$#array1) {
   die if $array2[$_] !~ /: creating "\Q$array1[$_]\E"$/;
}
```

Comment: If they are sorted. Otherwise can just sort them.

Comment: @Qtax, True, although there are solutions that scale better than sorting. For 100 elements, sorting would probably be faster despite the higher "complexity".

Comment: Why would his program want to die (or have to trap the die) just because the number of elements in the two arrays are not the same or if one of the elements doesn't match? @Qtax The question seems to say that the data are in order (both arrays blah1 through blah100), and whether they are or aren't, sorting will only put them in the wrong order until after the 'Name: creating ' prefix is removed.

Comment: @Joseph Myers, The OP didn't specify what he wants done, but 1) he did imply it's an error if they are different. ("What is the best route to **make sure** that all elements ...", emphasis mine), and 2) it's very easy to identify what needs to be changed if it needs to be changed (e.g. `s/die/return 0/`).

Comment: @ikegami I totally understand your code and what to do to make it work within a program, and probably the OP does too. But the fact is, that it isn't a self-sufficient answer. If I wanted to use it in a program, or even to run it and time it to test its efficiency, I would have to rewrite it first. I thought you were going for the first post and would complete your answer afterwards, but since you did not I respectfully submitted my own answer. Most importantly, your answer actually appears wrong to me. I do not think that "Name: creating" is a static string, but that Name may be variable.

Comment: @Joseph Myers, Re " If I wanted to use it in a program [...], I would have to rewrite it first." I wrote it for the OP, not you. As I already explained, your changes would not meet the OP's stated requirements. If you have different requirements than the OP and you need some help adapting the code, let me know.

Comment: @Joseph Myers, Adapted to ignore the "Name" part.

Comment: @ikegami Your updated code looks like it meets the OP's stated requirements. My code certainly does so (I always test my solutions), so feel free to remove your false comment that my code does not.

Comment: @ikegami And thank you, but no, I don't need any help with this. I've been a perl hacker and package writer for ~15 years, expert in almost all versions of it, even MacPerl for Mac OS 8. I am trying to be helpful to the community, which includes people who can't understand how to adapt your code with die into logic that works within their program. (And I suspect with about 100% certainty that Name is no more a literal value than blah1 & blah2.)

Comment: Re "My code certainly does so", You seem to be missing a die. Your code doesn't make sure the arrays are the same, it merely says whether they are or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would sort both arrays with the same rule and then compare one by one.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub checkall{
my @array1 = @{shift};
my @array2 = @{shift};

my @sorted1 = sort{ $a <=> $b } @array1;
my @sorted2 = sort{ $a <=> $b } @array2;

if( $#sorted1 == $#sorted2){
  for(0 .. $#sorted1)
  {
    #print $sorted1[$_] ."->". $sorted2[$_] ."\n"; #uncomment to see the comparison
    return "doesn't match!" if not $sorted1[$_] eq $sorted2[$_];
  }
  return "ok!";
}else
  {
    return "not same size!";
  }
}

my @array1 = (4,2,3,1);
my @array2 = (1,2,3,4);
print checkall(\@array1,\@array2);
```

Another version closer to the question requirements:

```
sub checkall{
    my @array1 = @{shift};
    my @array2 = @{shift};
    my $aux;

    my @sorted1 = sort ( map{ ($aux) = $_ =~ /Name\: creating \"(.*)\"/g } @array1 );
    my @sorted2 = sort @array2;

    if( $#sorted1 == $#sorted2){
      for(0 .. $#sorted1)
      {
        #print $sorted1[$_] ."->". $sorted2[$_] ."\n"; #uncomment to see the comparison
        return "doesn't match!" if not $sorted1[$_] eq $sorted2[$_];
      }
      return "ok!";
    }else
      {
        return "not same size!";
      }
    }
```

The difference is in the creation of a new list with a map and a pattern.

Comment: It's an example, just put your own sorting rules and comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use map to filter the needed parts from the second array and then compare the two with the smart matching operator (~~):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw(blah1 blah2 blah3);
my @arr2 = ('Name: creating "blah1"','Name: creating "blah2"','Name: creating "blah3"');

my @compare = map { local $_ = $_; s/^.+\: creating "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"/$1/; $_ } @arr2;

if (@arr1 ~~ @compare){
    print "all blahs there\n";
}
```

In this example its assumed both arrays are sorted already, if not just use "sort".

Comment: what a neat trick! im still debating whether to go with this route because this would pass if arr2 "just contains" arr1  ie arr2 can have whats in arr1 AND more.

Comment: What's `local $_ = $_; ` for? I don't think it's necessary

Comment: The `local $_ = $_;` is necessary because I didnt want to change @arr2!

Comment: It's described in detail here: [Using regex in Map function](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=613280)

Answer (score 1):

*Example Data*

```
my @array1 = qw(blah1 blah2);
my @array2 = split(';', 'Joe: creating "blah1";Bill: creating "blah2"');
```

*The first two lines following are a solution to your problem*

```
my @check = map { m/:.*?"(.*)"/g } @array2;
if (@array1 == @array2 && "@array1" eq "@check") {
    # note that @array1 == @array2 is only done for efficiency;
    # it would be sufficient to verify only that
    # "@array1" eq "@check"
    print "same\n";
} else {
    print "different\n";
}
```

Note that it would now be safe to sort `@array1` and `@check` in case your original arrays were not in corresponding order. (Sorting `@array` and `@array2` would only be likely to destroy any order that might have already been there because of the names prefixing the values in `@array2`.)

```
my @check = map { m/:.*?"(.*)"/g } @array2;
my $i = 0;
if (@array1 == @array2) {
    for (; $i < @array1; $i++) {
        last if $array1[$i] ne $check[$i];
    }
} else {
    $i = -1;
}
if ($i == @array1) {
    print "same\n";
} else {
    print "different\n";
}
```

Please note that this longer code is *only more efficient* if your arrays are **not** identical. If it is usually the case that you expect your arrays' values to be the same, then there is no benefit in using the longer code.

BTW: That regular expression looks careless, but according to the OP it is exactly what we want, especially if blah1, blah2, etc., may contain additional double quotes. If we are sure that no names contain quotes, then we can remove the `:.*?` and just do `"(.\*)"` alone, which would be faster.

Comment: My first suggested solution always works. For my second solution, you are somewhat correct. I correctly compare the length of both arrays in scalar context and correctly compare a sufficient number of elements to determine if they are not identical. However, the shortcut of only comparing `$i` to `@array1` assumes there is data in `@array1`. I will update to handle the case of `@array1 == 0`. Note that the OP said "`@array1` has data" so in fact, both of my solutions are correct. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should be fastest but only by very little margin compared to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17981329/49197)

```
die if @array1 != @array2;
my $i;
for my $e (@array1) {
   die if $array2[$i++] ne qq{Name: creating "$e"};
}
```

**Edit**:

If Name part of string is variable:

```
die if @array1 != @array2;
my $i;
for my $e (@array1) {
   die if $array2[$i++] !~ m/: creating "\Q$e\E"/;
}
```

Comment: Please note that "Name" cannot be assumed to be a literal value any more than "blah1" and "blah2." Solutions assuming otherwise are almost certainly wrong.